# Update value in Firebase and React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have added a menu in my database in firebase and now I want to edit the menu in the database. But whenever I send a request to update the menu it only updates the first menu. No matter which menu I choose, it always updates the first menu in the database.

This is my part of an editMenu component which has a button that links to EditmenuForm.

`

```
contentMenuKeys.map(t=>{
 // if (t === this.state.Appetizer)`

              return(
                <div className="text-center">
                  <h4>{t}</h4>

                  <div className="row">
                    {Object.keys(this.props.menu[t]).map(menu=>{
                      return(

                      [this.props.menu[t][menu]].map(item=>{
                        return(
                          <div className="col-md-6 menuItems" >
                            <div className="textM d-flex">
                              <div className="one-half">
                                <h3>{item.Name}</h3>
                                <p><span>{item.Description}</span></p>

                              </div>
                              <div className="one-forth">
                                <span className="price">${item.Price}</span>
                                <p><span>
                                  <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#MenuEditModal">Edit</button ><MenuEditForm Menu_Type={t} Name={item.Name}Description={item.Description}  Price={item.Price}iID={menu} rID={queryString.parse(this.props.location.search).id }/>{"   "}
                                  <button  type="submit" onClick={()=>{this.props.deleteMenu({rID:queryString.parse(this.props.location.search).id,Menu_Type:t,iID:menu})}} className="btn btn-danger ml-2">Remove</button>
                                </span></p>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        )
                      })
                    )
                    })
                  }`
```

And below is MenuEditForm component which has edit menu form.

```
 `import React,{Component} from 'react'
import {connect} from "react-redux"
import propTypes from "prop-types"
import { editMenu } from "../../actions/addMenu"
export class MenuEditForm extends Component {
    state={
        Name:"",
        Description: "",
        Price:"",
        Menu_Type:"",
        rID:""
    }static propTypes={
        editMenu: propTypes.func.isRequired
}`



    onChange=e=> this.setState({[e.target.name]:e.target.value});


    onSubmit=e=>{
        console.log("reached");
        e.preventDefault();

        const { Name, Description, Price, rID, Menu_Type } = this.state;
        const menu = { Name, Description, Price, Menu_Type, rID, iID:this.props.iID };

        this.props.editMenu(menu);
        this.setState({
            Name:"",
            Description: "",
            Price:"",
            Menu_Type:"",
        });

    }
    componentDidMount(){
        this.setState({rID:this.props.rID})
      }
    render(){const {Name, Description, Price, Menu_Type}=this.state;
        return(

            <div>
            <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
            <div className="modal fade" id="MenuEditModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div className="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div className="modal-content">
                <div className="modal-header">
                    <h5 className="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Edit Items</h5>
                    <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>

                    <div>
                        <div className="modal-body">
                        <div className="ml-4 mr-4 mt-4 mb-4">


                                <div className="form-group">
                                <label>Menu_Type</label>
                                <select name="Item Type" id="Item-Type" value={Menu_Type} onChange={this.onChange} name="Menu_Type">
                                <option value="None">None</option>
                                <option value="Appetizers">Appetizers</option>
                                <option value="Entrees">Entrees</option>

                                </select>
                                </div>

                                <div className="form-group">
                                <label>Name</label>
                                <input
                                className="form-control"
                                type="text"
                                name="Name"
                                onChange={this.onChange}
                                value={Name}
                                required
                                />
                                </div>

                                <div className="form-group">
                                <label>Description</label>
                                <input
                                className="form-control"
                                type="text"
                                name="Description"
                                onChange={this.onChange}
                                value={Description}
                                required
                                />
                                </div>

                                <div className="form-group">
                                <label>Price</label>
                                <input
                                className="form-control"
                                type="text"
                                name="Price"
                                onChange={this.onChange}
                                value={Price}
                                required
                                />
                                </div>
                        </div>

                        <div className="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" id="cancel" className="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary" >Change Items</button>
                        </div>


                        </div>

                     </div>
                     </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>

            </form>

            </div>
        )
    }}export default connect(null,{editMenu})(MenuEditForm)
```

This is my editMenu action

```
export const editMenu =(item) =>(dispatch)=>{
    axios
        .post("/api/database/editMenu", item)
        .then(res => {
            dispatch({
                type:EDIT_MENU,
                payload:res.data

            });
        })
        .catch(err=>
            dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.date,err.response.status)));
```

My editMenuAPI

```
class editMenuAPI(generics.GenericAPIView):
    permission_classes=[
        permissions.AllowAny
    ]

    def post(self, request):
        try:
            print(request.data)
            db = firebase.editMenu(request.data)
            return Response({
                "status": "success"
            })
        except:
            return Response({
                "status":"Disconnected",
                "msg": 'There was a problem'
            })
```

This is editMenu function in firebase.

```
def editMenu(request):   
db=credentials().database()
mType = request['Menu_Type']
rID=request['rID']
iID =request['iID']
print(request)
request.pop("Menu_Type")
request.pop('rID')
request.pop('iID')
return db.child('Restaurants').child(rID).child("Menu").child(mType).child(iID).update(request)
```

Comment: When you say "This is editMenu function in firebase." what do you mean? You are using a firebase cloud function? If so, why don't you just use the SDK? Also can you please post the `editMenu` action since that is the most relevant piece of code here

Comment: I have posted my editMenu actions @JoshPittman

Comment: I'm very confused. What happens at "/api/database/editMenu"? are you interacting with firebase as a rest api or have you written a cloud function that you are interacting with or do you have a server that is handling this request?

Comment: Yes I am interacting with firebase as a rest api @JoshPittman
That one is url path for editMenu
`path('api/database/editMenu',editMenuAPI.as_view())`